# Regioselectivity in the aldolcondensation towards (Z)-Jasmon

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, regioselectivity

In the synthesis of (Z)-Jasmone via aldol-condensation as shown below,
how can the observed regioselectivity be explained?
After all, it is also possible to form the side product shown below. I thought that at least with LDA, the sideproduct should be favored, while I assume that for milder bases such as KOH, the thermodynamic enolate is formed, finally leading to the desired (Z)-Jasmone. Are there any other reasons for the regioselectivity?

[image]

Comment: The entire reaction (not just enolate formation) is under thermodynamic control, so you get the tetrasubstituted alkene preferentially over the trisubstituted alkene.

Comment: @orthocresol OK, I see that the the tetrasubstituted ketone is thermodynamically favored, but isn't the last step, i.e. the formation of the unsaturated ketone, effectively irreversible?

Comment: The reverse of an E1cb step is conjugate addition of hydroxide to an enone, which isn’t unrealistic.

Comment: Not only ‘is not unrealistic’ but also rather likely, depending on the conditions involved. I’m too lazy to write up an answer now though … D=